# Powershell copy item into shared drive with username and password

Tags: powershell

I'm using powershell script to copy files from local computer to a network shared folder

the code is working fine with no issues when there is no authentication is required for the shared folder. I don't mind to include the username and password in the code because there is no restrictions for the users

```
$folder = 'D:\test'

$destfolder='\\192.168.2.76\ENT'
$filter = '*.AVI'                             

$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
IncludeSubdirectories = $true              
NotifyFilter          = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {



[int]$sleepTime = 500
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated


try {
    # **********check if the file is locked by another process (still being received from the soource)********
    function Test-FileLock {
        param (
            [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Path
        )

        $oFile = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $Path

        if ((Test-Path -Path $Path) -eq $false) {
            return $false
        }

        try {
            $oStream = $oFile.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, [System.IO.FileShare]::None)

            if ($oStream) {
                $oStream.Close()
            }
            $false
        }
        catch {
            # file is locked by another process.

            return $true
        }
    }
    #******** End of Function (test if file is locked) *****************
    # below line : will keep testing if the file is locked ************
    while (Test-FileLock $path) { Start-Sleep 10 }

    # below line: once the file becomes "NOT Locked" , copy the file to the destination folder *******
    Copy-Item  $path  $destfolder -Force -Verbose -PassThru 
}
catch {
    $error|Out-File  -FilePath d:\outlog.txt -Append
    $Error.Clear()
}
}
```

I get the error 'Access Denied' .
I will appreciate if someone could help me to include the username and password in the code.

Comment: Why put the function Test-FileLock inside the try block? `Copy-Item` also has a `Credentials` parameter.

Comment: "I don't mind to include the username and password in the code because there is no restrictions for the users." Hardcoding credentials in code is generally not a good practice.
As you've hardcoded the `$destfolder` in this script, you might consider running the script as a Windows Task and pass the required credentials for writing to the `$destfolder` when you save the task. This credentials (username) will be displayed as the 'Author' of the task.

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter to your `Test-FileLock` function.

```
param (
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
    [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
    $Credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty
)
```

This will create a safe credential object where you can store your credential without hard-coding them into your script. See also this link [How to Add Credentials To PowerShell](http://duffney.io/AddCredentialsToPowerShellFunctions).

You should then try to use

```
Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination $destfolder -Credentials $Credential -Force -Verbose -PassThru
```

If this does not work, please add your full error message and tell us which command breaks your code.

**Edit**

You can also store credentials on your machine and then retrieve them from the Credential Manager.

1. Install and import the Credential Manager from the PSGallery

```
Install-Module CredentialManager
Import-Module CredentialManager
```

2. Create a new account with `New-StoredCredential`

```
$cred = New-StoredCredential -UserName TestAccount -Password P@ssw0rd
```

3. You can retrieve the credentials with

```
Get-StoredCredentials | where { $_.UserName -eq TestAccount }
```

This object is now a secure-string type. This command and the next (Step 4) should be in your script to retrieve the credentials and convert them to a PSCredential object.

4. To create a PSCredential object enter:

```
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($cred.UserName, $cred.Password)
```

Now you got a PSCredential object which you should be able to use for Copy-Item also as a script.

Comment: please forgive my questions, I'm a beginner. After adding the above I'm now being prompted to enter user and password. this won't work since my script is watching folder and could run anytime. advise please

Comment: @EyadAlkhatib, I updated the answer. Try to store the credential in your manager and retrieve them whenever the script is running.

Comment: I've added the 5 lines you provided then i called `$credentials` in the copy-item statement , but i got this error : _New-StoredCredential : The term 'New-StoredCredential' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again_

Comment: That error means that the module is probably not imported for your script. Before calling `New-StoredCredential` import the CredentialManager module.